# The output shows zero, variable doesn't store the value

Tags: java

The main class:

```
package tdm;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author abbas
 */
public class TDM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("** WHAT DO YOU WANT TO FIND? **");
        System.out.println("1. (A) Duration of each input slot, (B) Duration of each output slot and (C) Duration of each frame");
        System.out.println("2. (A) Input bit duration, (B) Output bit duration, (C) Output bit rate and (D) Output frame rate");
        System.out.println("3. (A) Duration of bit before multiplexing, (B) The transmission rate of the link, (C) The duration of a time slot and (D) The duration of a frame");
        System.out.println("4. Find everything!!");

        int choice;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                Ex1 ex1 = new Ex1();
                ex1.calculateEx1();
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The Ex1 class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tdm;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author abbas
 */
public class Ex1 {

    public void calculateEx1() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int connectionsNum, dataRate, bitMultiplexed;
        System.out.print("Enter number of connections: ");
        connectionsNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the data rate (Kbps) for each connection: ");
        dataRate = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of bit(s)");
        bitMultiplexed = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("** Your question is **");
        System.out.println("The data rate for each one of the " + connectionsNum
                + " connections is " + dataRate + " Kbps. If " + bitMultiplexed
                + " bit at time is multiplexed, what is (A) The duration of each"
                + " input slot, (B) duration of each output slot and (C) duration "
                + "of each frame");

        System.out.println("** The answer is **");
        int inputSlot = (bitMultiplexed / (dataRate * 1000));
        int outputSlot = ((1 / connectionsNum) * inputSlot);
        int frameDuration = (connectionsNum * outputSlot);
        System.out.println(inputSlot);
        System.out.println(outputSlot);
        System.out.println(frameDuration);

    }

}
```

The output:

```
run:
** WHAT DO YOU WANT TO FIND? **
1. (A) Duration of each input slot, (B) Duration of each output slot and (C) Duration of each frame
2. (A) Input bit duration, (B) Output bit duration, (C) Output bit rate and (D) Output frame rate
3. (A) Duration of bit before multiplexing, (B) The transmission rate of the link, (C) The duration of a time slot and (D) The duration of a frame
4. Find everything!!

Enter your choice: 1
Enter number of connections: 3
Enter the data rate (Kbps) for each connection: 1
Enter number of bit(s): 1
** Your question is **
The data rate for each one of the 3 connections is 1 Kbps. If 1 bit at time is multiplexed, what is (A) The duration of each input slot, (B) duration of each output slot and (C) duration of each frame
** The answer is **
0
0
0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14 seconds)
```

As you can see, the three variables inputSlot, outputSlot and frameDuration should store the result of the expression. But as you can see in the output it shows 0. I think this is weird!! This is the first time something like this happen to me.

I suppose it's a small problem but I can't figure out what it's!!

Comment: If you're using an IDE, use your debugger and set some breakpoints. If you still can't find the problem, make a [mcve].

Comment: You are dividing integers. `(bitMultiplexed / (dataRate * 1000)` ... If `dataRate * 1000 > bitMultiplexed`, you get 0.

Comment: change the int to double. Maybe its something like 0.589 or so and it displays just the int part

Comment: yes exactly what @cricket_007 said.

Comment: It worked when I changed all the variables in the class to double. Damn, I wasted my time with trying to figure it out, I have never thought of this as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables have to be floats instead of Integers. Integers can only store integers as the name sais. Floats can store point nubers like 0.0002. If u divide the int 20 by 11 and store this as a int Java will put 1 as the result. So if your result is 1.9 it is 1.0 as int. That is the Problem here. It looks like this

```
float inputSlot = (bitMultiplexed / (dataRate * 1000));
float outputSlot = ((1 / connectionsNum) * inputSlot);
int frameDuration = (connectionsNum * outputSlot);
System.out.println(inputSlot);
System.out.println(outputSlot);
System.out.println(frameDuration);
```

If you have a question ask me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Enter the data rate (Kbps) for each connection: 1
```

Okay, so `dataRate = 1`.

```
Enter number of bit(s): 1
```

And `bitMultiplexed = 1`.

```
System.out.println(1 / (1000 * 1)); // 0
```

Need to cast to a float/double somehow, for example.

```
System.out.println(1 / (1000.0 * 1)) // 0.001
```

Answer (score 1):

As you program/answer suggests.

```
inputSlot = 1 / 10000 = 0;
output  = (1/3)*0 = 0;
frameDuration = 3 * 0 = 0;
```

Since these are int. It will strip the decimal part. Use BigDecimal or double for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises due to these 3 fields being initialized as ints. If you make them double your problem will be solved because when you declare them as ints, it will take just the integer part. So for example if you have 0.588 it will take just the 0 which is what is happening as of now.

```
int inputSlot = (bitMultiplexed / (dataRate * 1000));
        int outputSlot = ((1 / connectionsNum) * inputSlot);
        int frameDuration = (connectionsNum * outputSlot);
```

In order to solve this, you need to change the `int` to `double`.